# How to use php in wordpress template to modify on-page details?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, paypal

There must be a standard answer to this question which must come up all the time, but I haven't been able to find the solution.

I am trying to set up the return page from a PayPal payment on a Wordpress site.  I have a button on the sales page which sends the transaction to PayPal and once completed PayPal sends POST data back to a url for a page that I specify on my site.

The responding page on my site needs to perform a confirmation handshake with PayPal, read the POST data, email me with the details, and display a table to the customer with the details.  All except the last action can easily be done with php, but displaying the table (which should be the easiest) is where I'm stuck.

I have a draft "Thank you for your order" page on standard page in Wordpress.  I have created a custom template file which can be selected from the Templates dropdown selector on the Edit page.  The custom template can host the php code to perform the handshake, get the POST data and email me with the details.

However, the template (which is a copy of the Atahualpa theme's index.php file) renders the page by various Wordpress function calls, and I don't want to interfere with those.  However, this means that I can't directly control the page rendering using echo commands in php.  With javascript or jquery I could allow the page to load and then modify the innerHtml, but this seems to be a clumsy way of doing it, and it would probably be visible to the user, as page elements are first rendered then modified.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `What's the best way to do this?` : Don't use Wordpress. LOL! However, if you can't see a working example will be hard to answer you.

Comment: Why can't you use php echo? Use `<?= $infoVar; ?>` in your table cells.

Comment: @Marcos - Yes, I know `Don't use Wordpress`, but I don't have that liberty at this point.  `@amflare` `Why can't you use php echo?`  Because there's nowhere in particular in the template file to echo it to.  For example, the main post content is generated by `<?php bfa_post_bodycopy('<div class="post-bodycopy clearfix">','</div>'); ?>`.  The function `bfa_post_bodycopy()` is buried in some theme file and if it's modified it will revert with the next update.

Comment: Don't let guys like Marcos mock you out of using WP.  That's just ignorance.  The knowledge you are lacking is simply how to extend WordPress using hooks, building shortcodes, etc.  A shortcode is what you're after here.  You can build out the output of your table or whatever data you need to display, and then tie that into a short code, so in the WordPress page you would just put something like [paypal_pdt_output] and that would display the actual content you prepared in the PHP.

Comment: @AndrewAngell you don't know what is a joke, obviously.